# Get Coordinates around a point

Tags: ruby

I have trouble to find a good algorithm to get all points around a point(the mid point included)  in a coordinate system.

Example:

```
  1 1   2 1   3 1

  1 2   2 2   3 2

  1 3   2 3   3 3
```

I have the above grid, so for example if I input:
get_around_coordinates(2, 2, 1)

It would return an array which would look like this
[[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3,2], [3, 3]]

This is how my method looks like:

```
 def get_around_coordinates(px, py, radius)
    coord = []
    start_x = px - radius
    start_y = py - radius
    (radius * 2 + 1).times do |x|
      (radius * 2 + 1).times do |y|
        coord.push([start_x + x, start_y + y])
      end
    end
    return coord
  end
```

I hope that someone can give me something better than this.

Comment: Could you clarify "better". Faster? More concise? Do you absolutely need the full array, or would an `Enumerator` be useful?

Comment: How is defining `get_around_coordinates` (which takes three arguments) relevant to `get_coordinates` (which takes two arguments)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
def get_around_coordinates(px, py, radius)
  xs = (px - radius..px + radius).to_a
  ys = (py - radius..py + radius).to_a
  xs.product(ys)
end
```

Now let's imagine Ruby lacked this method. The functional approach would be a OOP list-comprehension (flat_map + [flat_map...] + map): `xs.flat_map { |x| ys.map { |y| [x, y] } }`.

Answer (score 0):

a rather crude method

```
  def neighborhood(x=0, y=0, radius)
    (x-radius..x+radius).reduce([]) { |neighbors, x1|
      (y-radius..y+radius).each { |y1| neighbors << [x1, y1] }
      neighbors
    }
  end
```

Comment: `to_a` is not needed. Note also that this imperative use of `reduce`+ `each` = functional `flat_map` + `map` (OOP list-comprehension of sorts).